# How can I recover data from an unmountable drive, and copy it to a new drive?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, data-recovery

I recently switched my media center back to Ubuntu 16.0.4 from Windows 7. I'm running separate TV Show and Movie drives, which contain all of the content for Plex. My Movie drive mounted perfectly fine, and I was able to configure it via `fstab`. However, my TV show drive shows bad sectors, and won't mount. Being that this drive is the one being written to the most (new content added daily, and also watched constantly), it makes sense that it would give out before the other.

I've ordered a new WD Gold drive of the same capacity to replace it, but I need to know if there is a way to recover the data stored on here, and copy it to the new drive.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first create a disk image, then try a recover. This is because you need to put as much data as possible in a safe place, especially when the drive is showing hardware failures (like clicks and noises).

For this you can use the ubiquitous `dd` tool. Something like this:

`dd if=/dev/sdx of=./disk.img bs=512 conv=noerror,sync status=progress`

where `sdx` is the device name as seen by Linux.
Check that you have enough free storage to create the disk image that will be as big as the maximum disk capacity.
As an option, especially if your drive is showing hardware failures, is to use `safecopy` (you'd need to first install it from the repos).

`safecopy` uses multiple passes to copy the disk with increasingly "deeper" means in order to extract as much data as possible. With non-broken hardware it's as fast as `dd`.

Once you have your image you can go on with tools like `testdisk` and `foremost` or `scalpel`, all available from official repos along with man pages.